# How to use System.assertEquals() for DateTime?

Tags: unit-test, datetime

I have the following test class:

```
public static List<Account> testAccounts(Integer numberOfAccounts) {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; i++) {
            Account acc = new Account(
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 11, 10, 43, 1),
                    CompletedDate = DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 11, 14, 44, 1)
            );
            accounts.add(acc);
        }

        return accounts;
    }
```

I need to know how to use System.assertEquals() for `CreatedDate` as well as for `CompletedDate` of type DateTime? Please share an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works just like any other version of `system.assertEquals`

```
system.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 11, 10, 43, 1), Account.createdDate);
system.assertEquals(system.now(), account.createdDate);
```

You can also add a descriptive failure message:

```
system.assertEquals(
    DateTime.newInstance(2018, 7, 11, 10, 43, 1), 
    Account.createdDate,
    'Date mismatch, make sure the account was created at the correct time'
);
```

**The only requirement here is that the type of the expected parameter (first param) matches the type of the actual parameter (second param).** In your case they should both be date/time values.

[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)

Comment: Note: millseconds are ignored by assertEquals, so as long as they're the same second, it'll pass.